# cannot start cas-overlay-template on windows - missing \etc\cas\thekeystore

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cas

I am trying to run https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template on Windows 11 and JDK 11 (Eclipse Adoptium 11.0.16.1), using the 6.5 branch. I have ran the "createKeystore" and "copyCasConfiguration" gradle tasks using gradlew.bat, and it created the files below:

1. c:/etc/cas/cas.crt
2. c:/etc/cas/thekeystore
3. c:/etc/cas/config/cas.properties
4. c:/etc/cas/config/log4j2.xml

when I tried to run "gradlew.bat run", it hit the following error:

```
2022-08-22 20:26:06,670 WARN [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext] - <Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: FaException in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164)
        at org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication.main(CasWebApplication.java:62)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:238)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1077)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:234)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: \etc\cas\thekeystore (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:235)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1313)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1074)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \etc\cas\thekeystore (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:184)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.getResource(CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.java:118)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:199)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:283)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105)
        ... 33 more
```

I believe this is due to Gradle thinking its running inside a Unix environment instead of a Windows one. Any changes I make to the c:/etc/cas/config/cas.properties file is ignored, which makes me believe that its looking elsewhere for the cas folder (not c:/etc/cas). Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the keystore location in spring config. You can pass the property either in cas.properties or with command line flags or ENV. Two examples:

Example: absolute windwos path

```
server.ssl.key-store=D:/dev/cas/etc/theKeystore.jks
```

Example: relative path

```
server.ssl.key-store=file:etc/cas/thekeystore
```

By the way, you can also change the location of the cas.properties file with the cas.standalone.configurationDirectory parameter. This is how I usually work in a local environment on Windows:

```
java -jar build/libs/cas.war --cas.standalone.configurationDirectory=etc/cas/config --debug
```

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone got any ideas?

Please read:
https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.5.x/installation/Troubleshooting-Guide.html#review-logs

> CAS server logs are the best resource for determining the root cause of the problem, provided you have configured the appropriate log levels. Specifically you want to make sure DEBUG levels are turned on the org.apereo package in the log configuration

You could consider moving the configuration inside the CAS build itself  in an application.yml file, instead of keeping it outside.

https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.5.x/configuration/Configuration-Server-Management-Standalone.html

Answer (score 0):

Try switching from tomcat to jetty as an embedded servlet server. It seems to have better windows support, and *properly* looks for `c:\etc\cas\thekeystore`.

To do that just replace `-tomcat` with `-jetty` as `appServer` in the  `gradle.properties` file.

There might be a way to teach tomcat to look at the right place, but I didn't found it. The `server.ssl.key-store` setting didn't had any effect.